# Rename a column in microsoft sql server managment studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I rename a column in microsoft sql server managment studio?? I used this code but give me syntax error.

```
alter table sudents rename column old to new;
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188617.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sp_Rename` function

```
sp_RENAME 'sudents.[OldColumnName]' , '[NewColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'TableName.FieldName' , 'NewFieldName', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
sp_RENAME 'sudents.[OldColumnName]' , 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN'
```